# Moon-APNS; Array may not be empty or null. Parameter name: rawData

Tags: c#, .net, moonapns

I am new to .net coding. Right now I am trying to implement Moon apns to send notifications to one of my iphone application. When I run the application locally (with out hosting) it is working fine and I am able to send push notifications to ios app. I cross checked it and working great. But after hosting it in a server (which has no firewalls) I am getting the following error. I am unable to understand what's the wrong I did. My code is as follows and I got exception like ***"Array may not be empty or null. Parameter name: rawData"***

Code:

```
string message = string.Format("{0} has sent you a text chirp", username);
var payload1 = new NotificationPayload(token, message, int.Parse(badgeNumber), "default");
payload1.AddCustom("MessageType", "MessageTypeText");
payload1.AddCustom("Sender", toFbID);
payload1.AddCustom("AlertMessage", message);
payload1.AddCustom("MessageID", msgid);

var p = new List<NotificationPayload> { payload1 };

push = new PushNotification(true, "aps_development.p12", "chrip");

var rejected = push.SendToApple(p);
foreach (var item in rejected)
{
    contxt.Response.Write(item);
}
```

Can anyone help on this? I tried with development and production p12 files but no use.

Edit:

Log  info:

```
  20130923 1538 - Info - Payload queue received.
  20130923 1538 - Info - Connecting to apple server.
  20130923 1538 - Info - Creating SSL connection.
  20130923 1538 - Info - Conected.
  20130923 1538 - Error - An error occurred while reading Apple response for token       fb8a5834e2921f717ac83ce4ecdfd651922bbf81340bc133776bd55772fe6269 - Input string was not in a correct format.
  20130923 1538 - Info - Payload generated for fb8a5834e2921f717ac83ce4ecdfd651922bbf81340bc133776bd55772fe6269 : {"aps":{"alert":"hiiiiiiiiiii","badge":123}}
  20130923 1538 - Info - Notification successfully sent to APNS server for Device Toekn : fb8a5834e2921f717ac83ce4ecdfd789452bbf81340bc133776bd55772fe6269
  20130923 1538 - Info - Disconnected.
```

Thank you,
Chandra.

Comment: *Where* are you getting the exception?

Comment: @JonSkeet I am getting it after var p = new List<NotificationPayload> { payload1 };

Comment: @JonSkeet, Please have a look at my question edited with log information

Comment: That sounds very unlikely to me. Please show the full stack trace. Note that your log suggests that it's actually in the `int.Parse` call, given the "Input string was not in a correct format" part